# How to catch redirected URL in iframe?

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, iframe, cross-domain

We are loading a form using iframe, after submit form we are redirected to new URL(a web page).
Actually we want to get/catch that redirected url in our JavaScript code. we had searched a lot but did not find any solution that meet our requirement. help me to find solution. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, you can't use an iframe to monitor what a user does or where they navigate to on a third party site.

If you had control over the site in the iframe, then you could use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to signal the parent document with the information you wanted.